# Postgresql, insert value from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Right now, I have this table:

```
id|name|status (varchar)|fk_id_test (int)
-----------------------------------------
1 |ABC | X              |
2 | DX | Y              |
3 | ZZ | X              |
4 | TU | Y              |
5 | EE | Z              |
```

I have to insert in `fk_id_test` values coming from `status` column.

The algorithm would be something like:

```
switch(status)
    case 'X': `fk_ik_test` = 1
    case 'Y': `fk_ik_test` = 2
    case 'Z': `fk_ik_test` = 3
etc.
```

The result should be this:

Right now, I have this table:

```
id|name|status (varchar)|fk_id_test (int)
-----------------------------------------
1 |ABC | X              |1
2 | DX | Y              |2
3 | ZZ | X              |1
4 | TU | Y              |2
5 | EE | Z              |3
```

I have 5 `status`. This is because I will use another table (test) with the names of those status (varchar).

It's possible to do this in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses an `update` with a join:

```
update t
    set fk_id_test = v.fk_id_test
    from (values ('X', 1), ('Y', 2), ('Z', 3)) v(status, fk_id_test)
    where v.status = t.status;
```

Comment: Wonderful and flawless. Took 1:40 min to update my 16M registries :D

Answer (score 1):

do you  need update

```
 update table_name
 set fk_id_test= case status when 'X' then 1
    when 'Y' then 2
    when 'Z' then 3 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
case status
    when 'X' then 1
    when 'Y' then 2
    when 'Z' then 3
etc.

end as fk_ik_test
```

Comment: I need to persist the data in the table, I need to create new data in this new column, The table didn't have it, now was recently created and empty of course.

Comment: That's not adviced. You could create a view instead, adding the fk_ik_test column.

Comment: I have to fill the new field